# How to add keydown or keyup event listener to the mavon-editor

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm developing my project with `Vue.js`, and I use the component `mavon-editor` to edit markdown text, I want to do something when we edit the text in the mavon-editor and press the key such as `down`, `up` or `enter`.

I have tried the `@keydown` but it didn't work, how could I implement it, or it can't be done? Here's my code.

```js
<el-popover v-model="showMavonSuggestionList" popper-class="suggestions-popover" ref="suggestionPopover" placement="top-start" width="200" trigger="manual">
  <mavon-editor
    ref="mavonInput"
    slot="reference"
    :toolbars="markdownOption"
    v-model="template.entryContent.text"
    @input="handleMavonEditorInput"
    @keydown="handleMavonKeyDown"
  />
    <ul v-if="mavonSuggestionList.length > 0">
      <li v-for="(suggestion,index) in mavonSuggestionList"
        :key="index" :value="suggestion.key"
        @click="selectMavonSuggestion(suggestion)"
        :class="{'selected' : index === mavonSelectedIndex}"
      >
        {{ suggestion.key }}
      </li>
    </ul>
</el-popover>
```

```js
<script>
  ...

  handleMavonKeyDown(event) {
      console.log(event);
      if (this.showMavonSuggestionList) {
        if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
          event.preventDefault();
          this.mavonSelectedIndex =
            (this.mavonSelectedIndex - 1 + this.mavonSuggestionList.length) % this.mavonSuggestionList.length;
        } else if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
          event.preventDefault();
          this.mavonSelectedIndex = (this.mavonSelectedIndex + 1) % this.mavonSuggestionList.length;
        } else if (event.key === 'Enter') {
          if (this.mavonSelectedIndex >= 0) {
            this.selectMavonSuggestion(this.mavonSuggestionList[this.mavonSelectedIndex]);
          }
        }
      }
    },
  
  ...
</script>
```